# Magento redirecting without codes

Tags: php, magento

I am stuck with an abnormal error in magento. I was developing an eCommerce site using magento .

Suppose the domain is  abc.com,
I installed magento in it and was making the website, due to some error I again installed magento in its subdomain ab.abc.com hence I wrote a redirect code in the index page of abc.com , redirecting it to ab.abc.com.

```
<?php header('Location:http://ab.abc.com'); php>
```

Now when I have removed the above code from the index page, still it is redirecting into its sub domain.

I am confused how is it redirecting without the redirection code

Comment: Try to delete the cache folder through ftp?

Comment: and also check the base url secure and unsecure in admin

Comment: ok checking, will let you know

Comment: I think you have used the database which is already used in ab.abc.com,If it is so, you can change the base url in Database

Comment: clearing chache did not help me.

Comment: Then check the base url in admin or in database you are using for abc.com

Comment: yes i am checking the base url, will let you know in 2 mins

Comment: both are abc.com   I hope it should be the main domain only

Comment: Hey thanx i made, yes it was pointing to the subdomain, now it is working very fine